# How to check if the USER is already created in the database or not in SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Is there is a way that from it I can know if the user(**not** the login) is already created in the database? I mean the user not the login, since, I know how to check for the login. I need to check for the user that is created inside a specific DB & a role assigned to it.

This is the code for checking for the login:

```
SELECT name FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = 'test_user'
```

but how about the user? Since I need to create the user and assign a role to it if its not created. Otherwise, I will continue without creating.

Thanks

Answer (score 75, accepted):

How about:

```
USE (your database you want to check the user's existence in)

SELECT * 
FROM sys.database_principals
WHERE name = '(your user name to check here)'
```

`sys.server_principals` shows you the logins defined on the server level - `sys.database_principals` shows you the principals (e.g. user accounts) on a database level.

Comment: @marc_s: I assumed that the user iN CREATE USER may not match the login in CREATE LOGIN. eg `CREATE USER marcs FROM LOGIN gbn`

Answer (score 14):

This will tell you the matching user name for a given login name

```
USE MyDB
SELECT
    sp.name AS ServerLoginName,
    dp.name AS DBUserName
FROM
    sys.server_principals sp
    LEFT JOIN
    sys.database_principals dp ON sp.sid = dp.sid
WHERE
    sp.name = 'MyLogin'
```

Comment: This is the more correct answer. The SQL Login might be mapped to a database User with a different name.

Comment: @themilkyninja, You may have to apply both checks (that one and marc_s's one). If you're going to create a user with specific name, then you have to check that the user name is available (by running the marc_s's check). In addition, due to 1-to-1 link between login and user you must check that no user is associated with the login (by running the gbn's check).

Answer (score 8):

```
use SomeDatabase
go

/* built-in system function */
select database_principal_id('UserNameHere')

/* check if exists and drop */
if database_principal_id('UserNameHere') is not null
    drop user 'UserNameHere'
go
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you please elaborate on your answer for future users to better understand your response.

Answer (score 3):

If you've found `sys.server_principals`, I'm surprised you haven't found [`sys.database_principals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187328.aspx). You can join the views based on the `sid` column.

Answer (score 3):

You might care for this method as well...

```
IF DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID('domain\lanid') IS NULL
BEGIN
    CREATE USER [domain\lanid] FOR LOGIN [domain\lanid] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
    EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_ApplicationUserRole', N'domain\lanid'
END
```